# 401 error when consuming a Web service with HTTP Basic authentication using CXF

Tags: java, web-services, client-side, cxf, basic-authentication

I'm trying to consume a remote Web service that uses HTTP basic authentication, using Apache CXF, within a JUnit test.

The error I am getting is:

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Failed to access the WSDL at: http://localhost:8080/services/MyService?wsdl. It failed with: 
    Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://localhost:8080/services/MyService?wsdl.
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.tryWithMex(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:151)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:133)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(WSServiceDelegate.java:254)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:217)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:165)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:93)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:76)
    at com.wave2.marketplace.importer.impl.adportal.ws.MyServiceService.<init>(MyServiceService.java:37)
    at com.wave2.marketplace.importer.impl.adportal.MyWSTest.testConsumingTheWS(MyWSTest.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:168)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:110)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:128)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:113)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:232)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:227)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://localhost:8080/services/MyService?wsdl
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1269)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1029)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.createReader(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:793)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.resolveWSDL(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:251)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:118)
    ... 26 more
```

---

Having read [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705728/how-do-i-consume-a-web-service-protected-with-http-basic-authentication-using-the), I have attempted to add the auth credentials to my request context, as follows:

```
@Test
public void testConsumingTheWS() throws Exception {
    URL wsdl = new URL("http://localhost:8080/services/MyService?wsdl");

    MyServiceService provider = new MyServiceService(wsdl); // <-- Error occurs here
    MyService service = provider.getMyService();

    BindingProvider binding = (BindingProvider)service;
    binding.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "username");
    binding.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "password");

    Ping out = service.getPing();
    assertNotNull(out);
}
```

However, as my in-line comment indicates, the error is occurring before the BindingProvider code is reached, so the error remains the same.

I did have a read of this [article](http://chrisdail.com/2008/03/31/apache-cxf-with-http-basic-authentication/) and its [follow-up](http://chrisdail.com/2008/08/13/http-basic-authentication-with-apache-cxf-revisited/), but so far I've had trouble determining how to go about adding the interceptor code without the use of Spring (this is for a JUnit test).

How might I go about authenticating against this Web service?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

According to [HTTP basic authentication with JAX-WS (Client)](http://etfdevlab.blogspot.com/2009/12/http-basic-authentication-with-jax-ws.html):

> #### 2. The service class creation
>
> A constructor of the service object
>   requires access to the WSDL. And again
>   it does not support basic
>   authentication out of the box. You
>   have an option to download the wsdl
>   file and use it locally. Another
>   option is to use the default
>   authenticator:
>
> ```
> Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
>     @Override
>     protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
>         return new PasswordAuthentication(
>             USER_NAME,
>             PASSWORD.toCharArray());
>     }
> });
> ```

Comment: Excellent! That has definitely got me further, I'm now getting a "MessageCreationException: Couldn't create SOAP message due to exception: XML reader error: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]". Any idea on what might be the issue here?

Comment: Oh, and I used the Authenticator.setDefault() approach. Using the wrong user/password fails as expected, so it looks like it is nearly working...

Comment: Thanks, guys!! It worked for me too. This site has the best answers!

Answer (score 6):

Just a point of note, you aren't using CXF.  You are using the JAX-WS reference implementation built into the JDK.

With CXF, you CAN use Spring config for everything and not set the default Authenticator.  See the page at:

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html

about the http-conf:authorization settings.

Comment: Thanks, I was inadvertently using JAX-WS. The Spring info will come in useful later too. Just wish I could mark 2 answers as accepted :)