# Java webservices - send object in request headers

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jaxb, jax-ws

I am using Jaxws to consume a webservice. while iam sending request i need to send an object in the request headers. When i am invoking the service from Soap-UI iam successfully getting the data. but the same in java i am unable to get it. I researched a lot on this any one know please help me how to do it.

Here is my java code

```
//getting the service
MyService servc = new MyService();
MyServiceSoap soap = servc.getMyServiceSoap();
//call the service
System.out.println(soap.SERVICE_A("123456789")); //getting null as response because i am not setting userid, password
```

I want to set the userid,password to the Authentication pojo object and set it to the soap headers and send the request. how i can do this.?

Here is my Soap-ui request screenshot
[Please see the SoapUI request format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/houaa.png)

My Questions is : How to send a java object in the soap request headers.?

Thanks in Advance,
Praneeth.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, what you're lacking is the [Basic Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) headers, where you pass the following in the HTTP header:

`Authorization: Basic <Base64(username:password)>`

Check in your SOAP-UI if the request sends this.

Here are some SO topics that may help you implement it:

1. [Java Web Service client basic authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071366/java-web-service-client-basic-authentication)
2. [How do I consume a web service protected with HTTP basic authentication using the CXF framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705728/how-do-i-consume-a-web-service-protected-with-http-basic-authentication-using-th)

Comment: No Baderous It is not working. Thanks for your attempt. Still strugguling how i can do it.